# Liquibase: Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file changelog/demofile.xml was not found in

Tags: liquibase

I have included a file in liquibase but [image]I am getting file not found

Error: Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file changelog/demofile.xml was not found in

Screenshot is attached for file structure and code

Comment: Can you please re-post your code as text? Also, please include the exact text of the error message as code as well?  Thanks! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see in your screenshot first of all your changelog file has an .yml extension and in the file it starts with an xml opening tag.

Regarding the error for not finding the file, try removing "changelog/" from the file path